# How to use select nodes through XPATH using // in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my input schema(xml):

```
<ns0:Catalog xmlns:ns0="http://Schema.InputSchema1">
<cd>
<cd1 ID="1" Title="Employee">
<Name>Prakash</Name>
<Salary>50000</Salary>
</cd1>
<cd1 ID="2" Title="Singer">
<Name>Ellie</Name>
<Salary>500000</Salary>
</cd1>
</cd>
</ns0:Catalog>`
```

and I am applying following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var=
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" 
version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://Schema.OutputSchema1"   xmlns:s0=
"http://Schema.InputSchema1">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Catalog" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/s0:Catalog">
<ns0:Output>
<xsl:for-each select="cd/cd1">
<ID>
<xsl:value-of select="//@ID"/>
</ID>
</xsl:for-each>
</ns0:Output>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am getting ID value everytime 1 while the looping is done 2 times.
what is tha actual use of // and how can I get all ID value  through // ?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//@ID"/>
```

selects all `ID` attributes that are descendants of the `/` root node, and returns the value of the **first** one of these (in document order).

In your example, you are already in the context of `cd1`, so all you need to do is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
```

--

Note also that this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Catalog" />
</xsl:template>
```

is redundant.

Comment: hi michael.thanks for ur reply. So what I got from your point is that://(element or attribute or node) only returns the value of first element/attribute/node in document order whether I am applying loop or not. Am I right ?

Comment: @PrakashSajwan Yes and no. The XPath expression `//abc` selects **all** elements named "abc" in the entire document, regardless of their position in the document hierarchy, and regardless of the current context.  The XSLT instruction `xsl:value-of` returns the value of the first node of all nodes selected by the `select` attribute (this is in XSLT 1.0; the result is different in XSLT 2.0).

Answer (score -1):

@Prakash,

U can use below XSL to get all ID values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select= "Catalog/cd/cd1">
<ID>
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
</ID>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ID>1</ID>
<ID>2</ID>
```

Comment: **1.** Your solution will not work with OP's input. -- **2.** Your output is not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Got your point michael what is //(node/element/attribute)means.           I think I can get my o/p as follows :
      <ID>  <xsl:for-each select="//@ID">  
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
      </xsl:for-each>
      </ID>                                                                Now I am getting all attribute as follows:<ID>1 , 2 , 200 , 500 ,</ID> Thanks